# What is the algorithmic time complexity, if the exact is ∛(n^2 )

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have calculated the answer to be n raised to 2/3 . Could anyone tell me what is the worst case Big O()

Comment: f(n)=O(f(n)) so surely you can just answer O(n^(2/3))

Comment: well just *O(root3(n^2))*, or *O(1000000*root3(n^2))*, and a lot of other *O(...)*s, for example *O(n^1234)*, but whether that is *worst case*, can not be answered with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is worst case or not that depends on the algorithm that you are using.

But in general, if you are having the number of operations to be `n^(2/3)` then the complexity in terms of `O-notation` is `O(n^(2/3))`.

Let me explain this in a bit more detail (so that we can get rid of the "general" word and give a definitive answer).

Consider a simple algorithm that finds the specific number in an array of `n` elements.

If your algorithm is something like this:

```
find(arr, number) {
    boolean found = false;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == number) {
            found = true;         
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

The time complexity to find a number in an array using the above algorithm is `O(n)` **always**. By always I mean that what so-ever is the input, the above algorithm will always have `n` iterations (considering the length of array is `n`).

Now compare and contrast this algorithm with the following:

```
find(arr, number) {
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == number) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now the time-complexity depends on the input of the array. (If you have an array with 10^8 elements and the first element matches with the element that you are searching for then you are done and you can instantly return without iterating over the whole array). So the worst-case complexity here becomes `O(n)` but the best case here is `O(1)`.

So it basically depends on your algorithm how it is working. I assume that your intent when you say "exact" is that you have first version of `find` that I described above. And if that is the case then yes, the worst-case time complexity is `O(n^2/3)`

Comment: The program for which I found this complexity is, "a^3+b^3 = c^3+d^3 < n where n is given and we need to find a,b,c,d. I first found the cube of all values and then used a HashMap to store the sum of two cube values along with the two unknowns". What is the time complexity of this program. Is it O(n) or O(n^2)?